# How to split and get comma separated string inside a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I want to pass a string like `('abc', 'xyz', '', '', ..)` as a parameter to a stored procedure and inside the procedure get some value from select query using the values from input and save them in output variable.

Something like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEMO
    (@V1 VARCHAR(1000), @V2 VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @V2= CONCAT(NAME,VALUE) 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ID IN (-- LOGIC TO SPLIT THE @V1 VARIABLE)
                 -- HERE @V1 IS ('abc','xyz',..) )
END;
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: what is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEMO
    (@V1 VARCHAR(1000), @V2 VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @V2= STRING_AGG (CONVERT(nvarchar(max),CONCAT(NAME,VALUE)), ',')
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ID IN 
        (
          SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@V1,',') 
        );
END;
```

Comment: above code returns only the last comma separated value.

Comment: @radhikabahirat No it does not. It returns comma separated list of values.

Comment: Let me rephrase my first comment. The function splits and return a comma separated list but when used inside a query, the query uses only last value returned by the split function. That is the main issue.

Comment: Could you show what's the value you are passing as `@V1` and some data from `TABLE1`?